# Are the units of a ring $\Bbb {Z}_n, +, •$ also the generators of the cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}_n, + $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I noticed while studying for an introductory Algebra course, that the units $ x $ of $\Bbb {Z}_n, +, •$ had to be integers so that $\gcd(x, n) = 1$. But aren't those elements generators of $\Bbb {Z}_n, +$ too?

As far as I can tell, yes. But is there an underlying reason, theory or something to back this? Or is this just it?

Comment: Correct. The units are exactly the generators of the additive group. I think this applies only to these prime rings (= the rings with a cyclic additive group). May be more can be said?

Comment: Yes,  we can always replace $R$-module generators by any associate (which includes unit multiples).   Generally $R$-modules are preserved by unimodular transformations (e.g. a diagonal matrix of units, which multiplies each generator by a unit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion is the same for each.

That $\operatorname {gcd}(a,n)=1$ is equivalent to $a$ being a unit, since by Bezout, this is when $\exists x,y$ such that $xa+yn=1$, or $x=a^{-1}$ exists.

The second fact is because $1$ generates $\Bbb Z_n,+$.  And hence so does $a=a\cdot 1$ for any a such that $\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)=1$.  That's because $\vert a\cdot 1\vert=\dfrac n{\operatorname {gcd}(a,n)}=n$.